# How to get last index of each row?

Tags: java

I would like get last index of each row of my grid for replace the "." by "t".

Here is what I have for the moment :

[image]

So far I have only managed to do this on one line. I had tried to do it on several lines but it did not work I found myself with an offset of 1 for each line.

My code :

```java
for (int rows = 0; rows < size; rows++) {
    for (int columns = 0; columns < size; columns++) {
        if (divisibleBy3(rows) && divisibleBy3(columns)) {
            builder.append(pos);
        }
        else if(endArray >= (size*size-1) - size + 1 && endArray <= (size*size) - 1){
            if(divisibleBy3(endArray)){
                builder.append(pos);
            }
            else {
                builder.append(voidCase);
            }
        }
        else {
            builder.append(voidCase);
        }
        endArray++;
    }
    if(endRow == size - 1){
        builder.setCharAt(endRow, 't');
        endRow = 0;
    }
    endRow++;
    builder.append("\n");
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code causing the observed behaviour is, that `endArray` has always the same value. Thus you are replacing the char at the same index over and over again. Something like this would probably work as intended:

```
if (endArray == (rows + 1) * size) {
    builder.setCharAt(endArray + rows - 1, 't');
    endRow = 0;
} else {
    endRow++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution but I get the same result as in the image above.